# ios how to run the alarm sound in background

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, ios8

I am developing an alarm App. At the time while alarm is playing sound, if the app is in  open (foreground) then it executes the

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Method & alarm sound plays successfully.

But at time while playing the alarm sound if my app is in inactive/ background state then it not called the above method.

So is there is any way so that i can play alarm sound in background also. For now when my app is in background only the notification is arrive & no sound/song is playing.

Below is my Code

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
        musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

        [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
        [musicPlayer play];

        [self showReminder:@"Alarm ON!"];
}

- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alarm"
                                                        message:text delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Snooze",@"Ok",nil];
    [alertView show];

}
```

I just wanted to know how can play a song when the app is inactive/background and also show alert to stop / snooze the alarm.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you get this to work ?

Answer (score 3):

For Foreground:
[-application:didReceiveLocalNotification:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:)

For Background:
[-application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:)

But `Apple` recommends that,

**[Note: An alarm is not intended to serve as a UILocalNotification. An alarm requires you to create an event or reminder that is visible in the user’s Calendar or Reminders app. A UILocalNotification is better suited for general purposes that don’t involve the Calendar database.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ConfiguringAlarms/ConfiguringAlarms.html)**

[image]

[Apple Documentation about Configuring Alarms](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ConfiguringAlarms/ConfiguringAlarms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below is my Code,you mabey have a try!

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
 musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

    [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
    [musicPlayer play];

    [self showReminder:@"Alarm ON!"];
 }
```